# How to remove border on ul li last child

Tags: html, css

I have set the border on `:after` pseudo element on every li.

```css
.menu_bottom ul li{
    float: left;
    color: #00a0dc;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.menu_bottom ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #00a0dc;
    padding: 5px 12px;
}
.menu_bottom ul li:after{
    content: "";
    border-right: 1px solid #00a0dc;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 3px;
    height: 11px;
}
.menu_bottom ul li:after:last-child{
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_bottom">
   <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">our services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Don't know how to remove border on last child. Used `:after:last-child` but it doesn't work.

Comment: try `:last-child:after` instead `:after:last-child`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class selector to avoid the last child.

```css
.menu_bottom ul li{
    float: left;
    color: #00a0dc;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.menu_bottom ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #00a0dc;
    padding: 5px 12px;
}
.menu_bottom ul li:not(:last-child):after{
    content: "";
    border-right: 1px solid #00a0dc;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 3px;
    height: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_bottom">
   <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">our services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change:**

```
.menu_bottom ul li:after:last-child {
```

**To:**

```
.menu_bottom ul li:last-child:after {
```

```css
.menu_bottom ul li{
    float: left;
    color: #00a0dc;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.menu_bottom ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #00a0dc;
    padding: 5px 12px;
}
.menu_bottom ul li:after{
    content: "";
    border-right: 1px solid #00a0dc;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 3px;
    height: 11px;
}
.menu_bottom ul li:last-child:after{
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_bottom">
   <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">our services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```